# MVC Route not found although declared

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing

I got the following routes declared:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
             name: "SurveyContent",
             url: "Survey/{action}/{id}",
             defaults: new { controller = "Contents", action = "List", id = 3, type = 3 }
         );

         );                
        routes.MapRoute(
             name: "ItemCreation",
             url: "{controller}/Create",
             defaults: new { controller = "Contents", action = "Details", id = 0 }
         );
        routes.MapRoute(
             name: "OpenContent",
             url: "Open/{code}",
             defaults: new { controller = "Courses", action = "OpenContent", code = "" }
         );
```

I am trying to access the link **localhost/Survey/Create**, but returns me a 404 error. Later on I added

```
        routes.MapRoute(
             name: "SurveyContent1",
             url: "Survey/Create",
             defaults: new { controller = "Contents", action = "Details", id = 0, type = 3 }
         );
```

under the SurveyContent, but that didn't change anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Put ItemCreation route before all routes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The route:

```
url: "Survey/{action}/{id}",
```

Will match `Survey/Create`, before:

```
url: "{controller}/Create",
```

So place `ItemCreation` before `SurveyContent`.

In the route table, order matters.